# how to change blackberry profile programmatically?

Tags: blackberry

Thanks in advance,

I want to force blackberry device to the silent mode and return to the original profile through my program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't be done through the API. Some developers have had success using input simulation, but that requires permission from the user. Informed users won't allow input simulation unless the program is highly trusted. I won't allow any programs that request input simulation on devices connected to my BES.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get it done with input simulation? I've been unluckily trying to do so...

Comment: How to make this by input simulation?