# Mute other audio

Tags: java, audio, blackberry, java-me, audio-player

I need to be able to mute other audio playing on the device when my application is playing something - similarly to how the media player will stop when you receive a phone call.

There is the `PriorityControl` interface in `javax.microedition.amms.control` (as part of JSR-234) but according to my own research and to the BlackBerry Knowledge Base article ["Advanced Multimedia Supplement API - What's Supported"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Advanced-Multimedia-Supplement-API-What-s-Supported/ta-p/770659) it is not supported/implemented on the BlackBerry OS.

Is there any other way to do this on BlackBerry?

The app I'm working on is playing audio messages when they come from the network so I'd like to be able to give them priority of some sort so the user could hear them. Any other suggestions how to do that are very welcome.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9431310/813951

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. You can adjust the volume of your own player, but you cannot control sound played by other apps. You could change system volume using `EventInjector` hacks to inject virtual volume key presses, but this would also affect your app.